# Insert statement with possible default / null values

Tags: mysql

I have a **database** structure as follows:

```
col1 INT not null default_none primary
col2 VARCHAR null null
col3 VARCHAR null null
.
.
.
col9 VARCHAR null null
```

I prepare the following query in php. Values for col1, col4, col7 cannot be null. The rest would be based on what the user inputs. I have defined **$table** and all other required variables

I prepare an **INSERT** statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($col1, '$col2 ' , '$col3 ', '$col4' , '$col5 ', '$col6 ', '$col7', '$col8 ', '$col9 ').
```

But **mysql** reports an error. Am I correct?

**ERROR:** #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

**My TABLE STRUCTURE :**

```
Field   Type        Null    Key     Default     Extra

colNo1  int(10)     NO     PRIMARY      NULL    
collNo2 varchar(10) YES         NULL    
colNo3  varchar(10) YES         NULL    
colNo4  varchar(10)  NO         NULL    
colNo5  varchar(10) YES         NULL    
colNo6  varchar(10) YES         NULL    
colNo7  varchar(10) NO          NULL    
colNo8  varchar(10) YES         NULL    
colNo9  varchar(10) YES         NULL
```

Comment: "done in php"? PHP doesn't have databases.

Comment: It is a good idea to specify the column names on the insert even if you don't have to. The approach you use is likely to create bugs if your table structure ever changes.

Comment: @JohnFx: That is merely for the purpose of illustration.

Comment: r u able to insert data using phpadmin? if yes, then instead of query just type `DESCRIBE myTable`... you will get structure... **I am sure, col2 to col9 ALL are NOT varchar**

Comment: INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (54, , , 'news', '', '', 'bean', '', '', 'palm', '', '') does not work.

However, if I don't leave any val null, the query works.

Comment: can you try removing extra spaces that you have at " '" by "'"

Comment: even tried that. i.e. _,'','',_ ...

Comment: Now, declared every field to a common data type, and initialised 9 vars to '0'; Works fine.

Comment: Please take more care over your questions. This is a complete shambles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated in comments that your query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (54, , , 'news', '', '', 'bean', '', '', 'palm', '', '')
```

All the PHP is completely irrelevant to the question, which is about the above testcase.

Those empty parameters are illegal. Write `NULL` if you want null fields...

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (54, NULL, NULL, 'news', '', '', 'bean', '', '', 'palm', '', '')
```

...or provide an argument list that omits the fields that you do not wish to populate.

Answer (score 3):

Always specify the column names so you're not screwed by a schema chance, and always, **always** escape your variables. You have no excuse for putting in arbitrary plain-text in your query. If you're using PHP, use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to handle the escaping for you and make your queries easier to read.

It ends up looking more like this:

```
INSERT INTO `$table` (col1, col2, col3, col4, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The PDO placeholders will convert to `NULL`, a quoted string, a number, or whatever is required to properly insert any value you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in your SQL code.

Do you mean **$col7** ?

Comment: @user980411 : then update in question too

Comment: @FahimParkar: updated long ago!

Comment: still your query says `, $col7,`... WHAT ABOUT THIS??